# How do space launch providers calculate how many millipeople a rocket launch could kill?

Tags: launch, regulatory, cost-to-orbit

I was intrigued by [this post](https://mastodon.social/@wikkit/111896159238108598) which states...

> To get a license you have to show that your launch will kill no more than ~1 milliperson, which usually means not flying close to population centers.

I imagine this could be quite a complex calculation since there are many low-probability ways that a launch could fail. Can anyone summarize the expected casualty calculation process, while referencing, where possible, any publicly available documents on the topic?

While I will be happy to learn whatever you happen to know about this process, I would be interested in learning about the following details: a) Is this calculation generally outsourced to a third-party specialist company, b) If yes, what is the typical fee, c) Does it have to be recalculated for every launch, d) Who verifies the calculation, e) Are there any publicly available calculations, and f) Is there any information on how non-US agencies might perform the calculation differently?

Note: There is an FAA advisory on the topic [here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ast/licenses_permits/media/Ac4311fn.pdf).

Comment: You might find some information around the SpaceX SN8–SN9 timeline. SpaceX had used their own methodology for risk assessment. The FAA agreed that the risk was acceptable and granted a launch license, provided that SpaceX sends an updated risk assessment using the standard methodology. However, SpaceX launched SN8 without providing said document, which means they technically launched without a license. As a result, for the next launches, the FAA required that an FAA supervisor must be present in the control room. This caused some anger among the SpaceX fanbois because one launch attempt had …

Comment: … to be cancelled since the FAA supervisor got stuck in traffic. Anyway, I can't fully remember whether this risk assessment was about foreign property damage or casualties. But maybe you can find a press release by the SpaceX or the FAA, an article on Ars Technica or similar from around that time which sheds some light on this.

Comment: Apart from risk calculations, I wonder how many millipersons are killed by the environmental impact alone...

Comment: @gerrit Kudos - kind of a brilliant insight.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the calculations must be horrible. Someone somehow has to calculate a percentage chance of failure for each stage of the mission. Then run a series of calculations that assume that such a failure happens after 1, 2, 3, 4, x... etc seconds after launch.

Each member of the series must then be checked to see where the debris would fall calculating the Instantaneous Impact Point (IIP) in each case (more specifically the expected debris field area centered on the IIP).

They must then check to see the population density in that area and do some statistical calculations to see what the chance of hitting anyone would be.

Finally they need to sum up all members of the series to get a final result. Lots of statistics, lots of assumptions, approximations and data about populations and risks. Probably lots of technical arguments as well.

No doubt the process is somewhat automated, but I suspect that the above is roughly what happens.